# Filter on groups in oozie

Tags: oozie, oozie-workflow

From Oozie (4.2.0, from hdp2.6) I want to be able to get the list of jobs belonging to a certain group:

`oozie jobs -filter group=export`

But this filter never matches.
I set up the job with a few variables (while experimenting):

- variable `oozie.job.acl`
- variable `group.name`
- hadoop property `oozie.job.acl`

I can see (`oozie jobs`) the group name in the column `Group` (the one I gave for oozie.job.acl) but I cannot seem to use it in a filter.

Is there a trick I am missing or is it just not possible?

Comment: oozie jobs sometimes produce output in an awkward way. Can you try `oozie job -info <WF_ID>` to see if it indeed prints `group`?

Comment: @SivaprasannaSethuraman Yes it does. I can see the group as given by `oozie.job.acl`, as expected. I still cannot use it in a filter. It is as if the filter is completely ignored, it always shows all jobs, no matter the group name I give.

Comment: Interesting.. Could be a bug then.

Comment: Is https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OOZIE-2491 included in that release?

Comment: @gezapeti Unfortunately (and weirdly) the hortonworks git repo does not go far enough in the past for me to check. The oldest version in the repo has the patch, looking at version number I would think that my version has it as well but I cannot be 100% sure.